# Stochastic Gradient Descent Batching

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm new to regression and we are doing a very simple exercise in a course. I'm taking to get a basic understanding of GD and SGD for a linear regression.

From my understanding, the only difference between GD and SGD is that instead of performing the algorithm on dataset size m as is processing in GD, SGD performs the operation on subsets of m.

My question is, for SGD does one simply perform the algorithm on the mini-batch, or is there some sort of summation of the results to come out with a final answer? Apologies if I'm not asking in the correct terms, I'm newer to some of the mathematical concepts involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SGD you just feed an example to your model, compute the gradient of the loss function of that example and update the weights according to the gradient of the loss of that example.

In mini-batch gradient descent you feed a batch to your model, compute the gradient of the loss of that batch and update the weights according to the gradient of the loss of that batch.

In fact, SGD is mini-batch gradient descent with batch size equal to 1.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to figure out. Great, succinct answer.

Comment: I need 2 more rep points before I can :)

Comment: I tried to implement this, and included it in another post, I would be interested to see if you had thoughts on how I implemented the cost function and weight updates https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30786/implementation-of-stochastic-gradient-descent-in-python